# How do I select results that return rows that match the exact pattern and the first segment of that pattern?

Tags: postgresql

I have been poring over the PostgreSQL 9.0 documentation on Pattern Matching but I still don't understand how to get the results that I want.

Given the table `sandbox` that looks like this: `id, segment`

And contains this:

```
1, foo
2, foo-bar
3, foo-bar-baz
```

How I make it so when I select `foo-bar-baz` it also matches the "root" of the segment (which in this case is `foo`) and returns:

```
1, foo
3, foo-bar-baz
```

Likewise, searching for `foo-bar` will return:

```
1, foo
2, foo-bar
```

EDIT:

While a_horse_with_no_name's solution works just fine. I'd still like to know if there are other answers are out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sandbox
WHERE segment = 'foo-bar-baz'
OR    segment = (string_to_array ('foo-bar-baz', '-')) [1];
```

Comment: On the last line you meant to use `foo-bar-baz` instead of `foo-bar` correct?